I keep getting net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT on the console and (status) blocked on the network tab
i have this code that makes a request to fetch an array from a laravel backend, on my local server, it runs smoothly but after i hosted it, i keep getting POST error:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/retrieve net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

$.post("https://vgn.srgasaswsa.com", {
    // Retrieve CSRF token from the meta tag
    _token: document.querySelector(
        '#registrationForm [name="_token"]'
    ).value,

    // Send the value of the selected item as a parameter
    data: item.value,
})
    .done((res) => {
        // Loop it as options in the corresponding Local government <select>
        $.map(res, (item) => {
            $(local).append(
                ` <li class="hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-white hover:font-semibold">
                <label for="${item}" class="w-full h-fit relative" x-on:click="isFocus = false, message = '${item}'">
                    <input type="radio"
                                name="${local.substring(1)}"
                                id="${item}"
                                value="${item}"
                                class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-fit opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                    >
                    <p class="w-full h-fit py-2 text-[50px] lg:text-[1em] lg:text-base font-normal">${item}</p>
                </label>
            </li>`
            );
        });
    })
    .fail((xhr, status, error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

I changed the POST url affter hosting to the hosting url, but it still showing the same error,
this is my laravel cors
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['https://vgn.srgasaswsa.com'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,


Disable your adblocker.

Thanks, any way to walk around this ?

Hmm...Based on your cors configuration, it seems like you should be sending the request to "https://vgn.srgasaswsa.com/retrieve" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000/retrieve". Update the URL in your JavaScript code accordingly:
$.post("https://vgn.srgasaswsa.com/retrieve", {
});

Idk if it'll help
